# String XSLT namespace issue

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, kml, exslt

I have an XSLT file where I want to utilize a function in the `http://exslt.org/strings` namespace. My code below fails whenever the `str:tokenize` function gets called.

I'm currently using XslCompiledTransform as my processor in .NET 6.0. The error that I get back from that is as follows:

> Error: Cannot find a script or an extension object associated with
> namespace 'exslt.org/strings'.

This is my XSLT file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="1.0" 
    xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
    xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" 
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    exclude-result-prefixes="str kml fn xsl">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="kml:coordinates" />

    <xsl:template match="kml:kml">
        <nvg version="1.4.0"> 
            <xsl:apply-templates select="kml:Document"/>
        </nvg>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="kml:Document">
        <g>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@id"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="label">
                <xsl:value-of select="kml:name"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="kml:Folder"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="kml:Placemark"/>
        </g>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="kml:Folder">
        <g>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@id"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="label">
                <xsl:value-of select="kml:name"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="kml:Folder"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="kml:Placemark"/>
        </g>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="kml:Placemark">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="kml:Point"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="kml:LineString"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="kml:LinearRing"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="kml:Polygon"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="kml:MultiGeometry"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="kml:MultiGeometry">
        <composite>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="kml:Point"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="kml:LineString"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="kml:LinearRing"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="kml:Polygon"/>
        </composite>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="kml:Point">
        <point>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@id"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="x">
                <xsl:value-of select="str:tokenize(kml:coordinates, ',')[1]"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="y">
                <xsl:value-of select="str:tokenize(kml:coordinates, ',')[2]"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="label">
                <xsl:value-of select="(../../kml:name | ../kml:name)[last()]"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </point>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="kml:LineString">
        <polyline>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@id"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="points">
                <xsl:for-each select="str:tokenize(translate(kml:coordinates, ' &#9;&#10;', ' '), ' ')">
                    <xsl:value-of select="str:tokenize(string(.), ',')[1]"/>,<xsl:value-of select="str:tokenize(string(.), ',')[2]"/><xsl:value-of select="string(' ')"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="label">
                <xsl:value-of select="(../../kml:name | ../kml:name)[last()]"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </polyline>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="kml:LinearRing">
        <polygon>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@id"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="points">
                <xsl:for-each select="str:tokenize(translate(kml:coordinates, ' &#9;&#10;', ' '), ' ')">
                    <xsl:value-of select="str:tokenize(string(.), ',')[1]"/>,<xsl:value-of select="str:tokenize(string(.), ',')[2]"/><xsl:value-of select="string(' ')"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="label">
                <xsl:value-of select="(../../kml:name | ../kml:name)[last()]"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </polygon>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="kml:Polygon">
        <xsl:if test="kml:innerBoundaryIs">
            <composite>
                <polygon>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="@id"/>
                    <xsl:attribute name="points">
                        <xsl:for-each select="str:tokenize(translate(kml:outerBoundaryIs/kml:LinearRing/kml:coordinates, ' &#9;&#10;', ' '), ' ')">
                            <xsl:value-of select="str:tokenize(string(.), ',')[1]"/>,<xsl:value-of select="str:tokenize(string(.), ',')[2]"/><xsl:value-of select="string(' ')"/>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="label">
                        <xsl:value-of select="(../../kml:name | ../kml:name)[last()]"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </polygon>
                <xsl:for-each select="kml:innerBoundaryIs/kml:LinearRing">
                    <polygon label="Hole">
                        <xsl:attribute name="points">
                            <xsl:for-each select="str:tokenize(translate(kml:coordinates, ' &#9;&#10;', ' '), ' ')">
                                <xsl:value-of select="str:tokenize(string(.), ',')[1]"/>,<xsl:value-of select="str:tokenize(string(.), ',')[2]"/><xsl:value-of select="string(' ')"/>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </polygon>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </composite>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="not(kml:innerBoundaryIs)">
            <polygon>
                <xsl:copy-of select="@id"/>
                <xsl:attribute name="points">
                    <xsl:for-each select="str:tokenize(translate(kml:outerBoundaryIs/kml:LinearRing/kml:coordinates, ' &#9;&#10;', ' '), ' ')">
                        <xsl:value-of select="str:tokenize(string(.), ',')[1]"/>,<xsl:value-of select="str:tokenize(string(.), ',')[2]"/><xsl:value-of select="string(' ')"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="label">
                    <xsl:value-of select="(../../kml:name | ../kml:name)[last()]"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </polygon>
            <xsl:for-each select="kml:innerBoundaryIs/kml:LinearRing">
                <polygon label="Hole">
                    <xsl:attribute name="points">
                        <xsl:for-each select="str:tokenize(translate(kml:coordinates, ' &#9;&#10;', ' '), ' ')">
                            <xsl:value-of select="str:tokenize(string(.), ',')[1]"/>,<xsl:value-of select="str:tokenize(string(.), ',')[2]"/><xsl:value-of select="string(' ')"/>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </polygon>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This file to convert KML to a vector graphic has been given to me by someone who was given it by someone who was given it so basically everything has been lost in translation.

Any help would be very valuable if possible.

Thanks

Comment: Please start by identifying your processor - see here how: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25245033/3016153. Then explain how exactly the code "fails"; is there an error message? -- P.S. A namespace is not a website, and its existence as a website is completely irrelevant.

Comment: hi @michael.hor257k i'd like to add those two commands but i'm not sure where i would put them in my XSLT file. This is my first time ever working with this stuff so i'm very fresh. Thanks for your patience. From what i can see from a test xslt template I made with those two commands the Version is 1 and the vendor is Microsoft

Comment: That's too bad - see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5513438/17153010

Answer (score 1):

The specification of EXSLT has moved to http://exslt.github.io

However, the reason your code is failing is not because the specification has moved, it's because the functions you want are not implemented (or configured) in your chosen XSLT processor.

These days you'll probably find it easy enough to find a processor that implements XSLT 2.0, which has a `tokenize` function in the standard function namespace. EXSLT was basically a stop-gap solution until XSLT 2.0 was standardised, which happened in 2007.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Michael - for a processor I'm using .NET 6.0's XslCompiledTransofrm library. The error that I get back from that is as follows:

Error: Cannot find a script or an extension object associated with namespace 'http://exslt.org/strings'.

The same error occurs when I use http://exslt.github.io as well - is it just a simple swap out of the URL's? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Then the likely explanation is that Microsoft chose not to implement this function library. EXSLT is a specification, not an implementation; some XSLT vendors implemented it, others didn't. The namespace used in the function names is unrelated to the URL of the website that hosts the specifications.